# Agrupar itens da recyclerview pelo item.time semelhante ao facebook messenger

Tags: java, android-adapter

Estou tentando criar comportamento semelhante ao que acontece no Facebook Messenger, quando se enviar varias mensagens consecutivas, para isso criei vários *background drawables* com `border radius` diferentes para serem aplicados nos itens da `recyclerview` e dar a aparência de que um item tem relação com o outro.

Existe um método `addItem` que é usado para postar um novo item na conversa e nele eu tenho minha lógica que verifica se a paracarpo do tempo da última mensagem e a mensagem atual é inferior a 5 segundos, e se sim, é feito um `loop` para iterar os últimos itens da lista e aplicar o novo layout com base em alguns testes lógicos que irão decidir se o item terá a aparência de topo no grupo, de centro ou de rodapé, isso é feito através de 4 métodos do `adaptes`, sao eles: `setItemAsTop`, `setItemAsBottom`, `setItemAsCenter` e `setItemAsSingle` para o caso da mensagem não entrar no teste dos 5s, estes métodos simplesmente mudam o valor de uma variável e notificam a mudança, variável que é usada para aplicar o layout na celular no item em cada passada do `onBindViewHolder`.

O problema que tenho é que aparentemente quando chamo o `notifyItemChanged` em cada um desses metodos(setItemAs...) toda a lista é notificada ou sei lá, na verdade não entendo o que esta acontecendo, mas sempre o último comando `setItemAs`.. é aplicado na lista e nao na posiçao passada.

Segue o código relevante do meu `adapter`:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

public class MessageLayoutType {
    public static final int AS_TOP = 0;
    public static final int AS_CENTER = 1;
    public static final int AS_BOTTOM = 2;
    public static final int AS_SINGLE = 3;
}

private static java.util.Date lastMessageSendTime = new Date();
private static java.util.Date lastMessageReceiveTime = new Date();

private static int groupCountSend = 0;
private static int groupCountReceived = 0;

private MessageDialogViewHolder holder;

private static int MESSAGE_LAYOUT;
private static int MESSAGE_TYPE = MessageLayoutType.AS_SINGLE;

private static final int SENT_FROM_ME = 1;
private static final int SENT_FROM_OTHER = 2;

private List<Message> messageList;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
private User me;

public MessageAdapter() {
    this.messageList = new LinkedList<>();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MessageAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public void setMe(User me) {
    this.me = me;
}

public void addItem(int position, Message message) {
    messageList.add(position, message);
    notifyItemInserted(position);

    if (DateTimeUtils.getDateDiff(lastMessageReceiveTime, message.getTime(), TimeUnit.SECONDS) <= 5) {
        groupCountReceived++;

        Log.e("===DateTime===", "entrou no time" + groupCountReceived + " e agora o count é " + groupCountReceived );
        Log.e("count", groupCountReceived + " ");

        for (int i = groupCountReceived; i >= 0; i--) {

            if (i == groupCountReceived) {
                Log.e("===DateTimeType===", "is top" + i);
                this.setItemAsTop(this.getItemCount() - groupCountReceived);
            } else if (i >= 1 && i < groupCountReceived) {
                Log.e("===DateTimeType===", "is center" + i);
                this.setItemAsCenter(this.getItemCount() - i);

            } else if (i < 1) {
                Log.e("===DateTimeType===", "is bottom" + i);
                this.setItemAsBottom(getItemCount());
            }

            Log.e("===DateTimeFor===", "entrou no time previous message position: " + i);
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("===DateTimeType===", "is alone");
        this.setItemAsSingle(this.getItemCount());
        groupCountReceived = 0;
    }

    lastMessageReceiveTime = message.getTime();
}

public void setItemAsTop(int position) {
    Log.e("is noticed", " noticed as top");
    this.MESSAGE_TYPE = MessageLayoutType.AS_TOP;
    Log.e("MessageTYpeChanged", this.MESSAGE_TYPE + "");;
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public void setItemAsCenter(int position) {
    Log.e("is noticed", " noticed as center");
    this.MESSAGE_TYPE = MessageLayoutType.AS_CENTER;
    Log.e("MessageTYpeChanged", this.MESSAGE_TYPE + "");
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public void setItemAsBottom(int position) {
    Log.e("is noticed", " noticed as bottom");
    this.MESSAGE_TYPE = MessageLayoutType.AS_BOTTOM;
    Log.e("MessageTYpeChanged", this.MESSAGE_TYPE + "");
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public void setItemAsSingle(int position) {
    Log.e("is noticed", " noticed as single");
    this.MESSAGE_TYPE = MessageLayoutType.AS_SINGLE;
    Log.e("MessageTYpeChanged", this.MESSAGE_TYPE + "");
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public void updatedItem(int position) {
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final int layout = (viewType == SENT_FROM_ME) ? R.layout.adapter_generic_chat_list_right :
            R.layout.adapter_generic_chat_list_left;
    return new MessageDialogViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false));
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder myholder, int position) {

    MESSAGE_LAYOUT = (getItemViewType(position) == SENT_FROM_ME) ? R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_right_alone : R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_left_alone;

    final MessageDialogViewHolder holder = (MessageDialogViewHolder) myholder;
    final Message message = messageList.get(position);
    holder.attachEntity(message);
    holder.attachCallBack(onItemClickListener);

    Log.e("MessageTYpe", this.MESSAGE_TYPE + "");

    if (getItemViewType(position) == SENT_FROM_ME) {

        if (this.MESSAGE_TYPE == MessageLayoutType.AS_CENTER) {

            Log.e("===DateTimeTypeAdapter=", "is center" + position);

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_right_center;

        } else if (this.MESSAGE_TYPE == MessageLayoutType.AS_BOTTOM) {

            Log.e("===DateTimeTypeAdapter=", "is bottom" + position);

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_right_bottom;

        } else if (this.MESSAGE_TYPE == MessageLayoutType.AS_TOP) {

            Log.e("===DateTimeTypeAdapter=", "is top" + position);

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_right_top;

        } else {
            Log.e("===DateTimeTypeAdapter=", "is alone" + position);

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_right_alone;

        }
    } else {

        if (this.MESSAGE_TYPE == MessageLayoutType.AS_CENTER) {

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_left_center;

        } else if (this.MESSAGE_TYPE == MessageLayoutType.AS_BOTTOM) {

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_left_bottom;

        } else if (this.MESSAGE_TYPE == MessageLayoutType.AS_TOP) {

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_left_top;

        } else {

            MESSAGE_LAYOUT = R.drawable.bubble_bg_message_left_alone;

        }

    }



        holder.messageContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(holder.messageContainer.getResources().getDrawable(MESSAGE_LAYOUT));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageList != null ? messageList.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (me.equals(messageList.get(position).getSender())) {
        return SENT_FROM_ME;
    } else {
        return SENT_FROM_OTHER;
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onChatMessageItemClick(Message message);
}

static class MessageDialogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Bind(R.id.imageContentItem)
    ImageView picture;

    @Bind(R.id.imageItem)
    ImageView imageItem;

    @Bind(R.id.descriptionItem)
    TextView text;

    @Bind(R.id.titleItem)
    TextView personName;

    @Bind(R.id.spotLastMessageTime)
    TextView messageTime;

    @Bind(R.id.is_online)
    FrameLayout isOnline;

    @Bind(R.id.message_container)
    LinearLayout messageContainer;

    @Bind(R.id.layoutChatImageContainer)
    LinearLayout layoutChatImageContainer;

    @Bind(R.id.message_name_time_container)
    LinearLayout messageNameTimeContainer;

    private Message message;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public MessageDialogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void attachEntity(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void attachCallBack(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClickListener.onChatMessageItemClick(message);
    }
}
```

}